# checks the array's element total

Tags: visual-c++

In an integer array, how to check if there is a group of numbers sum equal to a given number? (use recursion)

- groupSum([2, 4, 8], 10) → true
- groupSum([2, 4, 8], 14) → true
- groupSum([2, 4, 8], 9) → false

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Top-down approach of DP.

Here is my C++ Implementation

```
bool groupSum (int arr[], int arr_size, int sum)
{
    // Base Cases
    if (sum == 0)
        return true;
    if (arr_size == 0)
        return false;
 
    // If last element is greater than sum,
    // then ignore it
    if (arr[arr_size - 1] > sum)
        return groupSum(arr, arr_size - 1, sum);
 
    // else, check if the sum can be obtained by adding or removing an element

 
    return groupSum(arr, arr_size - 1, sum)
           || groupSum(arr, arr_size - 1, sum - arr[arr_size - 1]);
}
```

for more info you can check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/)